# WebVR is deprecated, so will there be a a version of A-frame for webXR?

Tags: aframe

WebVR is now marked as deprecated at mdn. It will be replaced by webXR that is going to be a standard. Will there be a new version of A-Frame that supports webXR ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A-Frame already supports both WebVR and WebXR in version 0.9.2. FWIW, At the moment of writing this there's no browser that ships WebXR. WebVR is still the API to target for the next 3-6 months.